# Box authentication with API without user authorization

Tags: box

Question about Box authentication with API:

We have a requirement where in we need to interact with Box from a headless (non web) script, to do operations like saving file to Box folder / retrieve file from Box folder / tag a file or folder in Box etc.

Recommended Standard OAuth 2.0 requires app authorization by redirecting user to Box authorization URI (https://developer.box.com/docs/authenticate-with-oauth-2). I don't want to use JWT for security reasons imposed by my organization.

Is there a way one can circumvent this approach. We need absolutely no user interaction (even for input of user ID and password) when interacting with Box using APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I have automated interaction with the Box API using [this](https://github.com/matt-lindsay/box-nodejs-example) method. A Box app will have to be created, then authorised by an admin. If it is of any use I wrote the process up [here](https://mattlindsaysite.wordpress.com/2017/11/21/box-nodejs-sdk-authentication/).

You could make use of the [Box CLI](https://github.com/box/boxcli) which I've used to script bulk file uploads / manipulations.